# $u_{tt} = u_{xx}$ with unusual boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Solve using the reflection method $u_{tt} = u_{xx}$

With $ x< ct  , t > 0$ for some $c  \in \mathbb{R}$

And $u(ct,t) = 0, u(x,0) = f(x), u_t(x,0) = 0$

I thought of rotating the $t$ axis in order for the boundary condition to be $u(0,t') = 0$. Would that work? How to do that?

Comment: Is your equation is actually $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$ instead? If yes, then if you extend the domain to $x\in\mathbb R$ and set initial condition as $u(x,0)=f(x)\theta(-x)$, $u_t(x,0)=0$ where $\theta(x)$ is Heaviside theta, you will get the same solution for $x<ct$ because wave propagation speed will not exceed $c$.

Comment: @Ruslan: Maybe there's an error in the question, but I copied it correctly

Comment: What is $c$ then? If it's an arbitrary constant, then the equation is a bit harder.

Comment: @Ruslan: I thinks that it is just an arbitrary constant.

Comment: When $c=0$ , the solution can find in http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde201.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, a typo is suspected in the wording of the problem. Nevertheless, supposing that the EDP is :
$$u_{tt}=u_{xx}$$
The general solution is on the form :
$$u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)$$
where F and G are any fonctions (of course, at least two times derivable).

The boundary conditions are : 
$$u(ct,t)=F\left(ct+t)\right)+G\left(ct-t)\right)=0$$
$$u(x,0)=F(x)+G(x)=f(x)$$
$$u_t(x,0)=F'(t)-G'(t)=0$$
So, $G(t)=F(t)+$constant

which is the same as : $G(x)=F(x)+c$

$F(x)+G(x)=2F(x)+c=f(x)$
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x)-c)$$
$$G(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x)+c)$$
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x+t)-c)+\frac{1}{2}(f(x-t)+c)$$
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x+t)+f(x-t)\right)$$

The remaining condition $u(ct,t)=0$ leads to :
$$f(ct+t)+f(ct-t)=0$$
or, which is the same :
$$f\left( (c+1)x\right)+f\left( (c-1)x\right)=0$$

This is a functional equation. In the general case, any function $f$ is not solution and the problem has no solution.

But in the particular cases of function $f$ which is solution of the functional equation, the solution of the problem is :
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x+t)+f(x-t)\right)$$

Comment: Equation Differential Partial ? :P

Comment: For the problem with overdetermined quantities of conditions, we often consider piecewise solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem where the wave is reflected from a moving node. The solution should, according to [d'Alembert's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'Alembert's_formula), have a "forward" moving wave $f(x-t)$ and a backward moving wave $f(x+t)$. If the node moves with the speed smaller than wave speed, which here is $1$, i.e. $|c|<1$, then due to boundary at right there should also be a reflected wave $g(x+t)$. Now from [physical considerations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) we can guess how $g(x+t)$ looks. It looks like a Doppler-extended/compressed in spacetime backward-moving wave $f(x+t)$, namely

$$g(x+t)=-f\left(\frac{c-1}{c+1}(x+t)\right).$$

You can then check by substitution $x=ct$ that the solution
$$u(x,t)=\frac12\left(f(x-t)+f(x+t)-f\left(\frac{c-1}{c+1}(x+t)\right)\right)$$
satisfies the condition at moving boundary. It also satisfies the original wave equation and both initial conditions.

In the equations above $f(q)$ should be taken to be $0$ for $q\ge0$.

If $c\ge1$, then the node won't add any reflections, and you can just use the two first terms in the solution. If $c<-1$, then this will lead to creation of shock wave, and the solution may be singular near the boundary.

As for your idea of rotating $t$ to fix the boundary, I think you actually can do it, in a certain sense of "rotation": perform a [Lorentz boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) in the direction of the moving node, solve the equation with these spacetime coordinates with the fixed boundary node, then boost back to get the final solution.

Comment: Where is something strange in your result: $$u(x,t)=\frac12\left(f(x-t)+f(x+t)-f\left(\frac{c-1}{c+1}(x+t)\right)\right)$$
case $x=ct$
$$u(ct,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(ct-t)+f(ct+t)-f\left(\frac{c-1}{c+1}(ct+t)\right)\right)$$
$$u(ct,t)=\frac12\left(f(ct-t)+f(ct+t)-f\left((c-1))t\right)\right)$$
$$u(ct,t)=\frac12\left(f(ct+t)\right)$$
This is not consistent with the condition $u(ct,t)=0$

Comment: @JJacquelin that's OK. See my notice that $f(q)=0\;\forall q>0$. In the original problem setup $f(x)$ is not defined for $x>0$, and I extend the definition for it to be zero there to simplify the equations.

Comment: Ho yes ! I agree if the specification $f(x)=0$ for $x>0$ is added. This can be understood for some physical considerations. But if there is no additional condition on the form of $f(x)$, (such as the functional equation in my own answer), the boundary conditions given in the initial wording are non-consistent.

Comment: @JJacquelin Well, actually $f(x)$ can be _any_ twice differentiable function, and your reference to $f(ct+t)$ in your answer doesn't make sense because $f(x)$ is only defined for $x<ct=0$ since it's only an initial condition for $u(x,0)$.

Comment: I will no more argue because it appears that the mathematical description of the physical model is not fully expressed in the wording and the analytical solving needs to be oriented by some implicite physical considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $\begin{cases}x_1=x-ct\\t_1=t\end{cases}$ ,

Then $u_x=u_{x_1}(x_1)_x+u_{t_1}(t_1)_x=u_{x_1}$

$u_{xx}=(u_{x_1})_x=(u_{x_1})_{x_1}(x_1)_x+(u_{x_1})_{t_1}(t_1)_x=u_{x_1x_1}$

$u_t=u_{x_1}(x_1)_t+u_{t_1}(t_1)_t=u_{t_1}-cu_{x_1}$

$u_{tt}=(u_{t_1}-cu_{x_1})_t=(u_{t_1}-cu_{x_1})_{x_1}(x_1)_t+(u_{t_1}-cu_{x_1})_{t_1}(t_1)_t=-c(u_{x_1t_1}-cu_{x_1x_1})+u_{t_1t_1}-cu_{x_1t_1}=u_{t_1t_1}-2cu_{x_1t_1}+c^2u_{x_1x_1}$

$\therefore u_{t_1t_1}-2cu_{x_1t_1}+c^2u_{x_1x_1}=u_{x_1x_1}$

$u_{t_1t_1}-2cu_{x_1t_1}+(c^2-1)u_{x_1x_1}=0$

The conditions $u(ct,t)=0$ , $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=0$ become $u(0,t_1)=0$ , $u(x_1,0)=f(x_1)$ and $u_{t_1}(x_1,0)=0$ respectively and the problem converts to the problem of usual type.